# Swapping 2 substrings char by char by just changing chars place with space and one char at a time

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have a string, for instance:

```
"AAA UUU"
```

I want to receive:

`"UUU AAA"` at the end and print every step while getting to this solution.

But I can only change one char at a time and for example if I have

`AA UU` at the beginning I can only have

```
A AUU
AAU U
```

at the other time because I can only change a char's place with a space.

If I have

```
AAA UUU
```

At the next step I can have

`A AAUUU` or `AAAUU U` so the second char away from space can change too.

I know this question is a bit complicated but it is a problem that is really hard to explain. I would appreciate if you can guide me through some solutions or give me some advice about how I can solve this(I am open to any algorithm).

You can change the letters places and get the result desired with the code down below but I want to do it by just changing the chars with space and it does not do it:

```
// The Solution of Problem 2 begins
File file2 = new File(args[1]);
Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(file2); // The Scanner that is going to read file2.
ArrayList<String> solution2List = new ArrayList<String>();
try {  
    while(reader2.hasNext()) {
        solution2List.add(reader2.nextLine());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < solution2List.size(); i++) {

        if(i == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nThe 1st String:");
       }
       else if(i == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nThe 2nd String:");
       }
       else {
            System.out.println("\nThe " + (i+1) + "th String:");
       }

       System.out.println("The Original Form = " + solution2List.get(i));
       stringCharPlaceChanger(solution2List.get(i));

    } 
}
finally {
    if(reader2 != null)
        reader2.close();
}

public static void stringCharPlaceChanger(String stringToChange) {
    int indexOfSpace = stringToChange.indexOf(" ");
    char[] charArrayForProcessing = stringToChange.toCharArray();
    int changeAfterSpace = 0;
    char[] charAfterSpace = stringToChange.substring(indexOfSpace+1, stringToChange.length()).toCharArray();
    System.out.print("CHARSAFTERSPACE = ");
    System.out.println(charAfterSpace);
    int charAfterSpaceCount = charAfterSpace.length;

    // Sliding The Chars Before Space After Space.
    while(charArrayForProcessing[0] != ' ') {
        charArrayForProcessing[indexOfSpace] = charArrayForProcessing[indexOfSpace-1];
        charArrayForProcessing[indexOfSpace-1] = ' ';
        indexOfSpace--;
        changeAfterSpace++; // Incrementing When a Char Gets Past Right to the Space.
        System.out.println(charArrayForProcessing);
    }

    int changeAfterSpaceToBeIncremented = changeAfterSpace; // Initially.
    int indexCountHolder = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < charAfterSpaceCount; i++) {
        changeAfterSpaceToBeIncremented++;
        int changeCounterBack = changeAfterSpaceToBeIncremented;

        while(changeCounterBack != indexCountHolder) {
            char temporaryCharHolder = charArrayForProcessing[changeCounterBack];
            charArrayForProcessing[changeCounterBack] = charArrayForProcessing[changeCounterBack-1];
            charArrayForProcessing[changeCounterBack-1] = temporaryCharHolder;
            changeCounterBack--;
            System.out.println(charArrayForProcessing);
        }
        indexCountHolder++;
    }
```

**Left of the space can only be the same char like the right of the space can only be another same char.**

Possible Inputs:

- "AAA BB"
- "UUUUU CCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
- "A B"
- "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO PPP"

Outputs will be:

- "BB AAA"
- "CCCCCCCCCCCCCC UUUUU"
- "B A"
- "PPP OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"

Only the chars that are adjacent to space and the other 1 chars near them can change their places with space.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide another example or two if both inputs and outputs?

Comment: @notyou I am going to show the steps for "aa bb" -> "a abb"->"aba b"->"ab ab"->" baab"->"b aab"->"ba ab"->"baba "->"bab a"->"b baa"->"bb aa"

Comment: So is it always something like `bb cc -> cc bb` or `hhhhhh jjjjjj -> jjjjjj hhhhhh`?

Comment: As I read your code it reads strings that must be changed from a file. But how can it know what each string is to be changed to?

Comment: @notyou yes it is like them. It can be any long the length of substrings may be different too.

Comment: @OleV.V. each string must be changed to the form that the chars at the left side of space moved to the right of space and the chars at the right side of the space (in the beginning)moved to the left of space.

Comment: @SomeDude I am trying my best to provided concrete steps and give examples. Where did you get lost on the question? I may try to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my algorithm:

```
while there are chars to move from right to the far left:
 a. move a char from right to the far left
 b. reset position to next char to move
```

To do `a` I use this basic algorithm:

```
 1. a_b
 2. ab_
 3. _ba
 4. b_a
 5. check if we are in situation 2 and repeat from there
```

To do `b` I just move the space from left to right.

This is my implementation:

```
public class StringCharPlaceChanger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "AAA BB";
        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        System.out.println();

        String result = stringCharPlaceChanger(input);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Output: " + result);

    }

    public static String stringCharPlaceChanger(String stringToChange) {

        // input can not be null
        if (stringToChange == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: string can not be null");
            return null;
        }

        // index of space
        int x = stringToChange.indexOf(" ");

        // a space is required
        if (x == -1) {
            System.out.println("Error: no space found");
            return null;
        }

        // input converted in array
        char[] c = stringToChange.toCharArray();

        // number of chars on the left
        int numberOfLeft = x;

        // number of chars on the right
        int numberOfRight = c.length - x - 1;

        // length of the input
        int l = c.length;

        boolean first = true;

        // print of the original input
        System.out.println(stringToChange);

        while (numberOfRight > 0) {

            // after the first cycle
            if (!first) {
                // reset the position of the space near the next number to move 
                x = goTo(c, x, l - numberOfRight - 1);
            }
            else {
                first = false;
            }

            // move a char from right to left
            // basic algorithm:
            // a_b
            // ab_
            // _ba
            // b_a

            // a_b -> ab_
            x = swap(c, x, x + 1);
            for (int left = numberOfLeft; left > 0; left--) {
                // ab_ -> _ba
                x = swap(c, x, x - 2);
                // _ba -> b_a
                x = swap(c, x, x + 1);
            }

            numberOfRight--;

        }

        return new String(c);
    }

    // swap 2 chars
    private static int swap(char[] c, int i, int j) {
        char temp = c[i];
        c[i] = c[j];
        c[j] = temp;
        System.out.println(c);
        return j;
    }

    // go from left to right swapping chars
    private static int goTo(char[] c, int i, int j) {
        while (i < j) {
            if (i == j - 1) {
                i = swap(c, i, i + 1);
            }
            else {
                i = swap(c, i, i + 2);
            }
        }
        return j;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My idea for an algorithm:

1. Validate that the string fulfils:

   - it has exactly one space in it
   - it only has one char value (repeated) to the left of the space
   - it has one value (repeated) to the right
   - if required also validate that the left and right values are different
2. Repeat until result has been obtained:

   ```
    If the space is in the spot where it should be in the end
        swap it with some character that is in the wrong place
    else
        swap it with a character that should be where the
               space is and is not in its correct place
   ```

Thanks to qwertyman for pointing out that the latter will always be possible: if the space is not in its final place, then some other character should be where the space is, and since it isn’t, there is at least one copy of that character in a place where it shouldn’t be.

You will probably want to write a unit test. For each test case you should verify

1. that the correct end result is obtained
2. that each step swaps the space with one other char and leaves remaining chars in place.

For real-world code you would also unit test that the validation step catches all possible input errors. Whether that has any value in your situation, make your own judgement. I’d be very tempted to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have thought of a similar algorithm too. I will try to implement this.

Comment: +1, but I think that the last "else" condition is not necessary (can not occur) -- because if the space is not in its end spot, then it is in a spot where an A or a B should be. If _e.g._ it is in a place of A's, then it is impossible for all A's to be in the correct place (thus, if the space is not in the end spot, it can always be swapped with a character that should be where the space is).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation. Basically it works inwards from both ends, swapping one or both of the end characters with the space as required.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SpaceReverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
            "aa bb", "aa bbb", "aa bbbb", "aaa bb", "aaaa bb",
            " ", "Hello world", " Hello", "Hello ", " Hello "
        };
        for (String s : tests) {
            new SpaceReverse(s, System.out).run();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private final PrintStream ps;

    // new SpaceReverse("a b").run() just 
    // returns the result without printing anything while
    // new SpaceReverse("a b", System.out).run() prints each step

    public SpaceReverse(String s) {
        this(s, null);
    }

    public SpaceReverse(String s, PrintStream output) {
        if (!s.contains(" ")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no space in " + s);
        }
        sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        ps = output;
    }

    private void swap(int i1, int i2) {
        char c1 = sb.charAt(i1);
        char c2 = sb.charAt(i2);
        sb.setCharAt(i1, c2);
        sb.setCharAt(i2, c1);

        if (ps != null) ps.println(sb);
    }

    public String run() {
        if (ps != null) ps.println(sb);

        int lower = 0;
        int upper = sb.length() - 1;
        int space = sb.indexOf(" ");
        int newSpace = sb.length() - space - 1;

        while (true) {
            if (lower >= upper) {
                break;
            } else if (space == lower) {
                swap(lower, upper);
                space = upper;
                lower++;
            } else if (space == upper) {
                swap(lower, upper);
                space = lower;
                upper--;
            } else {
                swap(space, lower);
                swap(lower, upper);
                swap(upper, space);
                lower++;
                upper--;
            }
        }

        // if the space is not in the right place
        // one of these loops will move it there
        while (space < newSpace) {
            swap(space, space + 1);
            space++; 
        }
        while (space > newSpace) {
            swap(space, space - 1);
            space--;
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It gave me these errors:  .\SpaceReverse.java:1: error: modifier static not allowed here
public static class SpaceReverse {
              ^
.\SpaceReverse.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    private final PrintStream ps;
                  ^
  symbol:   class PrintStream
  location: class SpaceReverse
.\SpaceReverse.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    public SpaceReverse(String s, PrintStream output) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class PrintStream
  location: class SpaceReverse
3 errors

Comment: Since you are saving it in its own file, remove the word `static` from the first line and add the relevant imports and your package declaration (if any).

Comment: Ok it worked but there is a little problem.because only the letters that is mostly 2 chars away from space can change its place with space. ıf it is aaa bbb the rightmost and leftmost chars can not change their place with space. the others can.